# $X_1X_2$ in $Z_2[X_1] /(X_1^2+X_1+X_1)[X_2]/(X_2^2 +X_2 + X_1)$

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

Let $K = Z_2[X_1] /(X_1^2+X_1+1)[X_2]/(X_2^2 +X_2 + X_1)$
I’ve been trying to make the multiplication table for $K$ and haven’t managed to figure out what $X_1 X_2$ equals.
Any help?

Comment: I am quite uncertain about your notation. What exactly is $K?$

Comment: It is equal to (the coset of) $X_1X_2$. This is a 4-dimensional extension field of $\Bbb{Z}_2$ with one basis consisting of the cosets of $1,X_1,X_2$ and $X_1X_2$.

Comment: @Carlo In my opinion the only possible interpretation is that they first defined the field $F=\Bbb{Z}_2[X_1]/(X_1^2+X_1+1)$, and then the field $F[X_2]/(X_2^2+X_2+X_1)$ and in the step identified $X_1$ with the coset $X_1+(X_1^2+X_1+1)\in F$. Admittedly the notation is somewhere between horrible and unclear. I usually steer away from using the (former) free indeterminates as elements of the field, but frequently people do that (which may or may not contribute to the ensuing confusion).

Comment: I would denote $\alpha=X_1+(X_1^2+X_1+1)$ when $F=\Bbb{Z}_2(\alpha)=\{0,1,\alpha,1+\alpha\}$, then prove that $X^2+X+\alpha$ is irreducible in $F[X]$, and construct this extension field $F[X]/(X^2+X+\alpha)$. Some others find this "reusing of $X$" confusing. I guess it is all what you are used to. I want to name the element $\alpha$ because I find $X_1$ misleading as it really is the coset $X_1+(X_1^2+X_1+1)$.

Comment: Razivo, this is not unlike the field $\Bbb{Q}[X_1](X_1^2-2)[X_2]/(X_2^2-3)$ that you have hopefully seen denoted as $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$. Nothing much to do there with $\sqrt2\cdot\sqrt3$ other than call it $\sqrt6$, right?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, Yes, the intent was what you was saying. If it is a “new” element, what is the order of $K$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^2 + x + 1$ is the unique irreducible quadratic polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_2$, so the first stage of your construction gives the unique presentation of the finite field $\mathbb{F}_4 = \mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2 + x + 1)$. I will follow Jyrki in renaming this element, but I'll name it $\omega$ because it's a primitive third root of unity. Hence the elements of $\mathbb{F}_4$ are $\{ 0, 1, \omega, \omega^2 \}$. The second stage of your construction is

$$K = \mathbb{F}_4[x]/(x^2 + x + \omega).$$

To figure out what this should be we want to figure out how $x^2 + x + \omega$ factors over $\mathbb{F}_4$. Note that since we're working in characteristic $2$ the quadratic formula isn't available. Fortunately $\mathbb{F}_4$ only has $4$ elements so it's possible to just search exhaustively through all possible factorizations. The only possible factorizations given the linear term are

$$(x + \omega)(x + \omega^2) = x^2 + x + 1$$

and

$$(x + 1)x = x^2 + x$$

so we conclude that $x^2 + x + \omega$ is irreducible. Hence $K = \mathbb{F}_4[x]/(x^2 + x + \omega)$ is the unique quadratic extension of $\mathbb{F}_4$, namely $\mathbb{F}_{16}$. Accordingly it has a basis over $\mathbb{F}_4$ given by $\{ 1, x \}$ and so a basis over $\mathbb{F}_2$ given by $\{ 1, \omega, x, \omega x \}$.

Note that polynomials of the form $x^2 + x + a$ in characteristic $2$ are [Artin-Schreier polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Schreier_theory). Adjoining roots of such polynomials is a characteristic $2$ analogue of adjoining square roots.